# Cannot access combobox text property even if it has focus

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

Access says you can't access .Text property unless control has focus. But I'm sure that the control has focus because I'm in the change event of the combobox and Me.ActiveControl refers to the combobox; also SetFocus does not help.

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur if these conditions are met:

a) The combo is in the Form Header or Form footer section

b) The form is filtered such that no records match (or there are no records)

c) No new record can be added.

In this case, the Detail section of the form goes blank. The combo is still
visible, but Access gets really confused and can throw the error you
describe.

More info:
http://allenbrowne.com/bug-06.html